# Updating values in dictionary object

Tags: python, dictionary

My program has a `class Words` where a `defaultdict(int)` named `t_e_f` is created as an object and a function `main()` that contains a pointer to a function that uses the values of the dictionary 't_e_f' to compute other calculations. 't_e_f' is a dictionary having as key a tuple of words and as value a float number. 
My programs looks like this:

```
class Words:
     def __init__(init):
       self.t_e_f=Words.set_t_e_f(self)
     def set_t_e_f(self):
        raw_text_e=open_file('toyen')
        raw_text_f=open_file('toyde')

        tokens_e=raw_text_e.split()
        tokens_f=raw_text_f.split()+['NULL'] 

        tef_dict=collections.defaultdict(int)           
        for word_e in tokens_e_set:
            for word_f in tokens_f_set:
                tef_dict[(word_e,word_f)]=1/len(tokens_e_set)
        return tef_dict

     def get_t_e_f(self):
        return self.t_e_f
def main():
     words=Words()
     t_e_f=words.get_t_e_f()
     s_total_e=normalization(t_e_f)
```

I then have a `normalization` function that takes `t_e_f` and uses it to compute calculations over the values of another dictionary created in the normalization function, `s_total_e`.

```
def normalization(t_e_f):
    s_total_e=collections.defaultdict(int)

    words_sent_e=['the','big','book']
    words_sent_de=['das','grosse','buch']
    for item in words_sent_e:
         s_total_e[item]
    for item in words_sent_e:
        for item_2 in words_sent_de:
             s_total_e[item]+=t_e_f[(item,item_2)]
```

The problem is that when `t_e_f` is passed to normalization all the values are set to 0, therefore losing the initial values set when the words object was created. I was wondering what was happening and how to solve this problem.
Thank you.

Comment: You'll need to include the normalization function's code otherwise we won't know what it's doing.

Comment: .. and please include the t_e_f intitialization code.  You did not include any logic that actually mutates t_e_f, how are we supposed to diagnose the issue?

Comment: You should replace `1` with `1.0` in `1/len(tokens_e_set)` if you aren't using one of the newer Pythons with `true_division` as `1/2` is `0` without it while `1.0/2` is `0.5`.

Comment: I used from __future__ import division. Anyway before in the main() function after t_e_f=words.get_tef_dict() i inserted a print t_e_f statement and the dictionary contains all the floats correctly. However if I then print the dictionary as soon as the normalization function is called the values are all zeros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tef_dict` variable isn't being saved to the instance and is not being returned.  Add a line to `set_t_e_f()`:

```
return tef_dict
```

Also note that *defaultdict* will automatically add a zero entry even if you only lookup or inspect a missing key.

You may be better-off using [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) instead.  Unlike defaultdict, it will return zeros for missing keys but won't add them to the underlying dictionary.

Comment: I added the line return tef_dict. But it looks like it is not a problem of dictionary. Instead of collections.defaultdict I used a simple tef_dict={} but still when t_e_f is passed to normalization all the values are reset to zero and I do not understand why.

Comment: Worth mentioning here that `collections.Counter` is only available in Python versions 2.7 and above.